# Create table from SQL query in Spark (v.1.5.2)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a quite straightforward question, how can I create a table from an SQL query in `Spark(1.5.2)`?

I have seen that in the standard `SQL Server 2008`, this is solved the following way:

```
Select * into new_table  from  old_table
```

Is there any similar formula in Spark that does not require to use `.filter()` in the `Dataframe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First save your dataframe to "old_table" table

```
 df.registerTempTable("old_table")
```

Read your old table as new dataframe

```
val newDF=sqlContext.sql("select * from old_table ")
```

Save it again to spark sql

```
newDF.registerTempTable("new_table")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
create table "database.table_name" select * from "database.table_name" where "your_condition if any"
```